# Vue.js v-show function with data parameter

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to learn vue.js and javascript, so this is probably easy for those who already have walked the path... so please show me the way...

I want to have a universal function that passes parameters so...

in HTML

I have a call to function with div id parameter

```
<button @click="showdiv('user_likes')" type="button" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
```

In vue all the div elements are by default false.
This is my function in Vue.js methods

```
changediv: function(data){
        data==false ? data=true : data=false;

    },
```

All hints are appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you return a `!data` instead of that condition?

Comment: You are passing a string into `showdiv()` then testing if it is a boolean, so it will always be false. Try changing `==` to `===` or as @phaberest says use `data = !data`

Comment: phaberest & @Aron,  Yes returning !data is easier and Aron thank you for extended explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Button without a method

To complement the existing answer, since this case is a simple toggle, you can reduce the amount of code by getting rid of the method `showDiv` entirely. This should not be used if you have more complex logic since it could compromise readability: https://jsfiddle.net/8pLfc61s/

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
    <button @click="showParagraph = !showParagraph">Toggle paragraph with button</button>
    <p v-if="showParagraph">Hello!</p>  
</div>
```

JS

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        showParagraph: false
    }
})
```

---

## Checkbox with v-model

Another cool trick is to use a checkbox with v-model, although in this case the amount of markup is increased, so probably not a worthy tradeoff: https://jsfiddle.net/v09tyj36/

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">

    <label class="button">
      Toggle Paragraph with checkbox
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="showParagraph">      
    </label>

    <p v-if="showParagraph">Hello!</p>  
</div>
```

JS

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        showParagraph: false
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle that replicates what you're trying to to: https://jsfiddle.net/9wmcz2my/

HTML:

```
<div id="demo">
    <button @click="showDiv('showParagraph')">Click me</button>
    <p v-if="showParagraph">Hello!</p>  
</div>
```

JS

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        showParagraph: false
    },
    methods : {
        showDiv: function(param){
       this[param] = !this[param]
    },
    }
})
```